# Is there a way to continuously source a python file in interactive mode?

Tags: python-3.x, reload, python-importlib

Suppose I have file `foo.py`:

```
def foo():
 print("foo")
```

And I start an interactive session:

```
>>> import foo 
>>> foo.foo()
'foo'
```

Next, I add a function to the python file:

```
def bar():
  print("bar")
```

And I update my interactive session:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

So I realize I forgot that the import is cached:

```
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(foo)
>>> foo.bar()
'bar'
```

---

Is there an easy way to have the interactive session continuously update with any changes that accumulate in `foo.py`?

---

I had to add this for clarity, since there are a variety of ways this question can be misunderstood:

The specific purpose of this question is to be able to work in interactive mode EXACTLY the way interactive mode should be worked in, and be able to call functions that are written dynamically in another window, buffer, or context after a write to drive, *WITHOUT* entering reload.

In other words, I would like to eliminate unnecessary keystrokes (CTRL-R reload ENTER, for example) every time I pop back and forth between buffers.

Is there an *easy* way?

(it is ok if the answer is "NO")

Solutions that might create a solution, but are not "easy":

- a pile of code
- an interpreter-within-an-interpreter loop
- an application
- a novel interpreter effort
- a new ide company

An example of an easy way something similar is done:

- `pip install --editable my-dev-module`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: It seems this falls into a duplicated question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: @JuanMedina no, that is not relevant to my question

Comment: @JuanMedina I am asking how to continuously reload. I have already used `reload` in my question, so how could that be knowledge that I am seeking?

Comment: You see the loop on the answer?
`from importlib import reload  
import foo

while True:
    # Do some things.
    if is_changed(foo):
        foo = reload(foo)`

Comment: @JuanMedina that is an answer. Not a question. How can anyone reach an answer that is not searchable via the call of the question?

Comment: @JuanMedina it does not work.  The point of this question is to remove the `reload` ritual in interactive mode. Not to "do something in a while loop"

Comment: This is probably not possible because of the way python's `import` works -- it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope. This binding doesn't track the original module to detect changes, so unless you write an interpreter or a REPL that does that (which you don't want), reloading is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments you clarified you don't need to use reload. Although, I will list all the possible options I found. For Pythn you have only 2 options:

- use of `reload(foo)` (I know this is not the way you want, but exists)
- use of `importlib.reload(foo)`:

  ```
  import importlib
  importlib.reload(foo)
  ```

That's the only 2 options you have. Now, if you are using IPython, you have 2 more options:

- use `%run`: `%run foo.py`
- use `%autoreload`: the option you would be looking for is `%aimport foo`

For the entire explanation: https://switowski.com/blog/ipython-autoreload

If that doesn't answer your question, the the simple would be: Without using the first 2 option, it's not possible to do so

Comment: the first two options are the same option

Comment: the final option is not an interpreter

Comment: @Chris as far as I know, the only way to do this is to write custom code and auto-reload by listening when the file changes

Comment: @KetZoomer is correct. You could try checking the Sha256 of the file every few minutes in a second thread, and if it differs, reload the module, but that's all you can really do.

Comment: module to listen to file changes: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/